# What does it means when ModifyGraphWithDelegate throws error?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-lite, mediapipe

I am trying to run a tflite model in [mediapipe](https://github.com/google/mediapipe) which is using SSBO & tensorflow cpp lib. while initializing the delegate then ModifyGraphWithDelegate throwing following error.

```
E/libc++abi: terminating with uncaught exception of type absl::lts_2020_02_25::bad_any_cast: Bad any cast
A/libc: Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -1 (SI_QUEUE) in tid 25841 (mediapipe_gl_ru), pid 24342 (segmentationgpu)
```

[Here is my sample tflite model](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1KQ3dq_yHPQtdL8KNlPVA7uR_-YOBb0hl/view?usp=sharing).
My question is what exactly means when ModifyGraphWithDelegate throws error? What could be the meaning of above error log ?

Comment: Model looks fine for me and doable with GPU. I bet problems are on mediapipe side

Comment: @AlexK.[ThisModel](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1cdxG-B8upao_DMqjp8-wGIk7QSTq1Szn/view?usp=sharing) working fine with same pipeline.

Comment: Model from description works just fine with benchmark and GPU delegate.